# c++ string str=argv[index] causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I'm kind of new to c++ and I'm trying to override operator new.
I'm getting "segmentation fault". I did some printing and realized that the problem is when I try to get string of argv from command line arguments, but I don't understand why it is a problem- I did this before and it worked.

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    MemoryManager::getInstance(argc,argv);

 }


MemoryManager* MemoryManager::getInstance(){
    cout<<"empty getInstance\n";
    if(memMng==nullptr){
        bad_function_call();
    }
    return memMng;

}

MemoryManager* MemoryManager::getInstance(int argc,char* argv[]){
    if(memMng==nullptr){
        memMng=(MemoryManager*)malloc(sizeof(MemoryManager));
        memMng=new(memMng) MemoryManager(argc,argv);
        if(memMng==nullptr){
            throw bad_alloc();
        }
    }
    return memMng;

}

MemoryManager::MemoryManager(int argc,char* argv[]){
    if(argc<3){
        throw invalid_argument("invalid number of parameters!");
    }
    string str; 
    str=argv[2];//**problem might be here**
    cout<<"test\n";//it doesn't print test

    if(!isNumber(str)){
        throw invalid_argument("invalid size of heap!");
    }

    size_t size=atoi(str.c_str());
    if(size<0){
        throw invalid_argument("size cannot be negative ");
    }
    MemPool::setSize(size);
    memPool=MemPool::getInstance();
    begin=memPool->getPool();
    end=begin+size;
    current=begin;

}
```

Comment: are you sure you are passing argv array of command line arguments?

Comment: yeah, if I print argv[2] it prints fine

Comment: I don't see where you override the `operator new` in your code.

Comment: I didn't think it is relevant to the problem so it didn't copy it

Comment: If the replacement version of `operator new` calls `getInstance()` there's gonna be trouble. `str = argv[2]` allocates memory, so it will, in turn, call `getInstance()` from inside the call to `getInstance()`. Possibly recursive death, but it's impossible to say without the code for `operator new`.

Comment: Aside: if you must use `malloc` for some bizarre reason, you need to check whether it returned a null pointer before you attempt to construct an object in that memory, not after.

Comment: @PeteBecker not precisely... there are two different overloads. Its more like `memMng=(MemoryManager*)malloc(sizeof(MemoryManager))` will happen before `str=argv[2]` so `memMng != nullptr` but the placement new is still in progress :)

Comment: @grek40 -- maybe, but you don't know without the code for `operator new`. That's why I said **possible**.

Comment: @PeteBecker True, but it's highly unlikely that the `operator new` implementation would call the `getInstance(int argc,char* argv[])` overload.

Comment: @grek40 -- you **don't know what the code does**, so "highly unlikely" or "highly likely" is just guessing. The code sample **does not provide enough information** to analyze what it does.

Comment: Thanks you Pete :) ! I didn't think of that

Comment: Oveloading `operator new` is at least at the "intermediate to advanced" level, not the "kind of new" level.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).